# Insert with select giving duplicate key violation

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have a stored procedure that is in effect trying to do an upsert into a table. Consider the following:

```
create table dbo.myTable (
   id int not null constraint PK_myTable primary key (id),
   payload varchar(100)
);
```

In the stored procedure, I'm populating a temp table that has the same structure as the table with user input and then attempting the following:

```
insert into dbo.myTable
   (id, payload)
select source.id, source.payload
from #temp as source
left join dbo.myTable as target
   on source.id = target.id
where target.id is null;
```

When I test this in isolation (i.e. just the above statement, wrapped in an explicit transaction; test harness below), running a second instance will wait on a key lock. This is what I expect. However, what I'm seeing is that occasionally under load I'm getting a duplicate key error. How is that possible?

I understand that I have a couple of ways around it. I could put `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` on the primary key constraint. I could also wrap the insert statement in a try and swallow the error. And, in all honesty, I'm going to explore those options. But I'd like to understand how the second transaction gets the green light to do the insert.

---

Test Harness

```
insert into #temp 
   (id, payload) 
values 
   (1, 'test');

begin transaction
go
    insert into dbo.myTable
    (id, payload)
    select source.id, source.id
    from #temp as source
    left join dbo.myTable as target
        on source.id = target.id
    where target.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to understand, then you can easily get this error manually. Open SSMS. Create simple table there, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 id int not null primary key
)
```

Now open the transaction and make an insert:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
insert into test values(1); -- do not commit
```

Then open new window in SSMS and repeat the same statement there:

```
insert into test values(1);
```

Now go back to your first window and commit the transaction. In the second window you'll get:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__test__3213E83F2818DDD3'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'dbo.test'. The duplicate key value is (1).

I think that the most proper way to solve that issue is to use proper isolation levels.

Comment: Interesting. Yet, my code doesn't look like that. It looks like what I have in the question. That is, it's doing a left join against the table to be inserted into. Projecting your proposal onto that, I issued the commit in the first window. The second window came back successfully with `(0 rows affected)`. Which is what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, an explicit transaction starts with a BEGIN and is followed by either a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK neither of which is present. Also it is inappropriate to include a GO in a stored procedure. Please tell us why you need to insert a single record in a #temp table and then move the same to  myTable? You might want to try something like the following after providing for parameters @Id and @payload in the procedure:

```
;MERGE dbo.myTable AS target
USING (SELECT @Id,@payload) AS source (Id,Payload)
ON (target.Id = source.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (Id,Payload)
 VALUES (source.Id,source.Payload);
```

Note that the MERGE statement requires the preceding `;`.

An explicit transaction would not be required.

Comment: My sample code is the simplest reproduction that I can make. My actual procedure is several hundred lines long, most of which is not relevant to the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the primary key issue by utilizing a SEQUENCE object.

I'm not sure where you're creating your id value now, but if you create a SEQUENCE, say sqPayload, then call NEXT VALUE FOR sqPayload wherever you're assigning that id number, the ids will stay sequential and unique, no matter how many transactions are writing simultaneously and you'll never violate the primary key.

You might want to make that a BIGINT SEQUENCE. If you're already running into concurrency issues, you might burn through all the INTs, and that's just never any fun.

Comment: The ID value is being passed into the procedure. That is, it's not being generated by the table in question.

Comment: I saw that the base table didn’t have an identity on it, so I figured it was coming in. But where’s it coming from? If you’re getting primary errors, the source is creating those duplicate values, which you could avoid by drawing them off a sequence. Which, of course, might not be feasible depending on what the current source is.

Comment: PK and some sort of auto-incrementing value (i.e. identity, sequence) often go together, but not always. My actual use case is that the ID values are being generated externally and being sent to this system. I want to enforce uniqueness in this table, but this table is ultimately not responsible for the generation of ID values.